# str_replace and keeping original pattern [r]

Tags: string, stringr

Is it possible to keep original pattern when using `str_replace` function from `stringr` package?

I provide an example here:

```
A = "Linear Model"

A %>% str_view("l$")
A %>% str_replace("l$", "(ols)")

# I need results to be Linear Model(ols)
```

I am fully aware that we can use paste in this perticular example however this is just reproducible example for much bigger issues I am having and need solution using `stringr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a hack, but the general idea is to find the index where the match occured, split the string into two parts from that index and insert replacement in between using `paste`.

```r
library(stringr)
library(reprex)
#> Warning: package 'reprex' was built under R version 3.6.3

A = "Linear Model"

str_extend = function(string, pattern, replacement){
  matched_index_end = str_locate(string, pattern)[2] #[2] is to extract the end of matching string

  #split given string into two and paste three elements together
  first_part = str_sub(string, 1, matched_index_end)
  second_part = str_sub(string, matched_index_end + 1, length(string))

  paste(first_part, replacement, second_part, sep='')
}

str_extend(A, 'l$', '(ols)')
#> [1] "Linear Model(ols)"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think it should be `nchar(string)` and not `length(string)`. Otherwise, your length will always be 1 in that function.